# Initialise redux state from uri

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I wish to initialise a state (list) from a API endpoint.

What's the best way of doing this? For example, would you supply a starting state into the reducer, or would the starting state in the reducer be empty and somehow have an action for the new state?

I am considered using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to do this sort of thing, but a simple example of how to do the above would be great.

```
let startState = {}; 
//some form of URL fetch here or supply data through action?

const reducer = (state = startState, action) => {
    ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Async redux thunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435421/async-initial-state-react-redux-redux-thunk) - In short: not the best way to go about this. Load the state when the application needs it.

Comment: You need to call an action that updates the the makes an API call and then update update the store in reducer rather than initializzing it , you can refer this question to use redux thunk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341206/actions-must-be-plain-javascript-objects/45343435#45343435

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - I believe that is what I was looking for - cheers

Comment: @vogomatix consider upvoting the answers that help you, it increases their visibility and may help others as well

Comment: I upvoted yours already :)